# How to use own login pages instead of GLUU custom page?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, gluu

Any help is appreciated.

At present, for both Sign In and Sign Up, I am able to use OpenID Connect (OAuth 2) Authorization Code Flow. But during this process, I have to use the GLUU custom pages. GLUU pages were customized to look like our organization application login pages.

I am looking to use our own organization application login pages, instead of customizing the GLUU login pages.

How to use own login pages instead of GLUU custom page? Is it possible?

-- David.

Comment: @pinkpanther  any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In the gluu server there is a /custom directory and you can overwrite the files there. Full guide here: https://gluu.org/docs/ce/operation/custom-design/